# How can I obtain a function satisfying the following conditions?

Tags: limits

I'm sorry, I don't know what else to specify on the title..

the domain is all real numbers which $x \ne 1$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}$$f(x)=2$

$\lim\limits_{x \to -\infty}$$f(x)=-2$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \ 1+}$$f(x)=-\infty$

$\lim\limits_{x \to \ 1-}$$f(x)=-\infty$

$f(x)$ should not be a piece-wise defined function.

Could you please help? I could only draw what the graph would look like, I have no clue what the function could be.

Comment: Have you tried to define it piece-wise?

Comment: oh, I'm sorry... the condition was not to define it piece-wise...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
f(x) = \frac{2(x-4)}{|x-1|}
\end{align*}

Comment: thank you, and thank you for your previous comment too!! the one before you edited the answer I've been drawing the graphs and they fit perfectly,

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\frac{2(x-4)}{\sqrt{(x-1)^2}}$$

Comment: thank you very much!!